# Using uipickerview to change variable

Tags: variables, uilabel, uipickerview

I am new to Xcode and I'm stuck trying to assign number values to my UIPickerView rows.
What I would like to achieve is in my mind a simple task but I can't do it.
I have a picker with the words "weekly", "Fortnightly", "Monthly", "Annual".
I want each chosen word to be represented by a number hidden in my code.
My first thought was to alter the value of an integer based on the .text in the label my picker changes. e.g.

```
 /* double z = {(if payCycleLbl.text isEqual: @"Weekly"){
        double z = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", 52];}
        (else if payCycleLbl.text isEqual: @"Fortnightly"){
            double z = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", 26];}
        (else if payCycleLbl.text isEqual: @"Monthly"){
            double z = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", 12];}
        (else if payCycleLbl.text isEqual: @"Annually"){
            double z = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",1};}
                       } */
```

Im open to any approach as long as it keeps in mind the goal here is to allocate a number that changes based on the users selection, and can be used in other calculations throughout my script represented by a single 'double z' value.

Thank you for you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

declare `d` as global variable means declare `d` as `double` in .h file

and add picker view delegate

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    d=(double)row+1;
}
```

it assigns `d` whenever you select row like if you have "weekly", "Fortnightly", "Monthly", "Annual" in picker view so `row` variable is 0 for weekly , 1 for Fortnightly and so on ....

and by adding this delegate whenever you select any row then `d` is assigned to particular row index like if you select "Monthly" then `d` contains (2+1) `row+1`

Comment: thanks for that. This info alone wasnt the solution, but it gave my picker rows a number value and I was able to come up with the rest. So thank you.

Comment: Now I have a new issue where everything is working and calculating as I want it but for an unknowen reason I need to press the calculate button twice if it is the first calculation. If I use my clear button and populate my calculator again I only require one press of the calculate button. Any Ideas?

Comment: you can take boolean variable globally then set it as your requirement

like 'checkFlag' is my boolean variable and its global variable and i want to do some task when button two time pressed then

-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
chekcFlag=true;
}
'-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
if(checkFlag==True)
{
checkFlag=False;
//code for first time click
}
else
{
checkFlag=True;
//code For Second time Click
}
}'

Comment: thanks. I might try that. I masked the issue so the user doesnt know its happening by adding my calculate action to all text field as a "edit did finish" (sorry if thats not what it is acually called, I cant remember the excact wording). this makes it so the calculate action is happening alot and therefore nobody notices that you need to do it twice.

Comment: so now I have a picker with rows that represent variables that i can use in my code and all is well. I just noticed that If the row is on the selection the user wants, e.g. Weekly is default and weekly is what the user wants. The number value and .text don't populate. Is there a way to state a row in view did load.
i have tried this
[picker reloadAllComponents];
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
 and it changes what row the picker loads on but it doesn't select a row as such. just views it without making changes to anything it affects down stream. any ideas?

Comment: `NSInteger row;
        row = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
        NSString *fullName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ ", [arrGender objectAtIndex:row]];
        
        [txtGender setText:fullName];`

Here arrGender is array with all values like i take arrGender as Male and Female so you can take an array as you want and print it on controller as you want...